# Advice regarding dashboard design using Pivot Tables/Charts

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dashboard, filesize, pivot-chart

Can you please answer a technical question for me. I am building a recruitment database for Football (Soccer) data that I plan on presenting via a number interactive dashboards in the same workbook - one per position type (GK / CBs / FBs / CMs / WMs / CF).

Just a quick question regarding workbook construction. I plan on cutting the Pivot Charts and pasting into their relevant dashboards (seperate sheet) - a setup I copied from this dashboard walkthrough (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K74_FNnlIF8). However I will be using a high number of charts. In this instance would you recommend using a new sheet per table/chart or would you recommend having more than one pivot table/chart on each worksheet - I would need to do this horizontally across the sheet due to the large dataset I am working with may cause issues of overlap (if copied vertically and new data points are added).

For your info there will only be 1 data source sheet and 1 version of PivotCache but I will be building 6 dashboards on seperate sheets - each containing around 20 pivot charts (around 120 in total).

Just wondered what was better in terms of size performance. More sheets with less cells used? or Less sheets with more cells used?

Any advice would be very welcome. I am a complete Excel novice so PowerPivot/Power BI arent an option just now.

Thanks in advance,

Calvin

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, more cells used with fewer sheets it's the best option.

First of all, you reduce the external connections between sheets. And within one unique sheet, you can optimize the time for loading charts, graphics and automatic calculations and updates turning it off in Excel options. This is extremely useful for speeding up your file.